# Serialdata import python "every other data point"

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to read serial data of an arduino which has been somewhat successful. The values that will be read from the arduino is voltage and current. I'm now trying to differentiate the different variables but i have no clue how. The arduino is sending the values in the following order with 1 sec delay. Voltage, AMPs, Voltage, AMPs.
How could i differentiate these values in to different variables? 
Here is my current code which doesn't differentiate the variables at all.

```
import time
import serial
values = []
serialVoltage = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
voltage = serialVoltage.readline()
time.sleep(1)
while True:print(voltage)



void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      }

    void loop() {
      float voltageRead = analogRead(A0);
      float ampsRead = analogRead(A1);
      float calculatedVoltage = voltageRead / 103;
      float calculatedCurrent = ampsRead / 1;
      Serial.println(calculatedVoltage);
      delay(1000);
      Serial.println(calculatedCurrent);

      delay(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some of the output? Are voltage values obviously different than amp values? I think you'll want to try and separate the two on the raspberry side

Comment: If i use the code provided by holdenweb i get the following output: ('v', '4.03\r\n', 'A', '403.00\r\n') 
They are obviously different, 403 is not a correct value though since i haven't plugged in the sensor for current yet. I guess max amps will be about 10/13 amps in it's finished state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't need the `sleep`s on the raspberry Pi - `readline` will block until the output comes along.

You should structure your code to read the voltage and current separately:

```
while True:
    voltage = serialVoltage.readline()
    current = serialVoltage.readline()
    print("V:", voltage, "A:", current)
```

Note also that if you want to work with the string values returned by `readline` you should first explicitly convert them to numeric form.

Remember that `readline` returns a string that includes the line termination - these are the `'\r\n'` characters you mention in your comment. I can't see how the "bad values" you mention are being created, but it would probably be helpful if the Arduino output allowed you to discriminate between voltage and current values.

My suggestion would be that you actually print out both values on a single line from the Arduino in a format that can readily be decoded by your Python program. Since it appears that the Arduino will already be running when you run the Python program on the Pi you could then simply ignore the first (possibly partial) line that you read, which will guarantee that all subsequent lines are whole outputs.

The "odd values" you see are because I assumed since you used the form `print(voltage)` that you were using Python 3! Since you appear to be using Python 2 your `print` statement should probably read something like

```
print "V:", voltage, "A:", current
```

The interpreter will then print the output as a string, rather than trying to show you the value of a tuple containing the four things to be printed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! This seems to do the trick, the output is a bit strange though, ('v', '4.03\r\n', 'A', '403.00\r\n') is this what it is supposed to be? If i type float(voltage) i get an error sometimes telling me that the value is incorrect (4.03.404.00). Which is of course a bad value. The timing of starting the script seems to matter to avoid the error. What can i do to help avoid this error?

Comment: I updated the answer, which I hope will address the additional questions in your comment.

Comment: That print statement seems to work a bit better. When i removed the float(variable) i don't receive any error codes at all. The first two outputs seems to be wrong but after that everything sorts it self out and becomes correct. Are there any cons with printing the values as a string compared to a float or an integer?

Comment: No cons at all if you just want to _see_ them. Skipping the first line of input is a sound rule, since it guarantees you won't see (probably) bogus output. But the inability to distinguish between voltage and current outputs is something of a pain, which you can fix by changing the Arduino's output.

Comment: How would i do this? The printf statement doesn't work on arduino as far as i know. I tried adding a new line between the sent values. Like this: 
  Serial.println(calculatedVoltage);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.println(calculatedCurrent);
  Serial.print("\n");
  delay(1000);
But doesn't seem to make any difference. Is there a way to send a string and a floatvalue in the same line?

Comment: Found a solution to my problem. Used the rstrip function and the if statement.

Comment: Cool. Where there's a will there's a way!